# How to remove blanks from pivot chart in Excel 365?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, pivot-chart

I want to remove "(blanks)" from pivot charts in Excel 365. How do I do that?

I have data which contains blanks:

```
Hdr
"a"
"a"
<blank>
"b"
"c"
```

This leads to a pivot table like this:

```
Labels  Count of Hdr
a       2
b       1
c       1
(blank)
```

And a bar chart like this:

```
2 I
1 I  I  I
0 -----------------
  a  b  c  (blank)
```

Desired output:

```
2 I
1 I  I  I
0 -----------------
  a  b  c
```

So three bars for "a", "b" and "c" respectively but *no bar* for (blanks).

[Image of what I try to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1NqN.png)

What button/setting do I have to use to achieve this, if at all possible?

Many thanks,
Jochem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter out "(blank)" row labels in the pivot table by clicking on the little down-facing triangle next to "Row Labels" and un-ticking "(blank)" in the next menu.